# Buffer overrun error in project converted from VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I get buffer over run error in a project that is converted from VS2005 to VS2008.
I would like to know if there are any tools that can help find where the buffer overrun occurred.

Comment: Yes, the debugger works well.

Comment: Do you mean visual studio debugger?looking at the call stack, i could narrow down to a module where the error occurs. But that module still has many functions. So, is there any way to point out a function which generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using c++.

In microsoft c++ there is a compiler switch `/GS` to find out if there are buffer overruns. For details and how it works see [MSDN Compiler Security Checks In Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290051%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

At least in c#-developpment (but hopefully also in c++) there is a debugger option 
"Break when an exception is ..." that stops program execution if an exception is thrown (beacuse the the c++ runtime detected that there was a buffer overrun. In vs2010 it is under Debug/Exceptions ...

You can also use [Microsofts PREfast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that scans your sourcecode for potentially insecure functions (strcpy)

Comment: no i cannot "mention how to use prefast" because i only read about it but haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Because of difference in behavoiur of sprintf, a non null-terminated string was written beyond the array boundaries. This in turn corrupted the stack and resulted in buffer over run. /GS switch in visual studio reports a buffer overrun and thus can help finding out the reason for a system crash.